# Trying to check if a number is a palindrome through the use of strings

Tags: c, string, palindrome

I am trying to check if an input number is a palindrome. I am doing it through strings rather than ints. So, I am taking in a string and reversing it into another string. However, when I use the string compare function it does not give me 0, stating that the strings are not the same. Even when I put in for example "1001", both the input and reverse strings displays 1001. I have figured it out with other methods but am trying to understand what is wrong with this one in specific.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[100];
    char reverse[100];

    int numLen = 0;

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    printf("The number is: %s\n", input);

    numLen = strlen(input) - 1;
    printf("Length of string is: %d\n", numLen);

    for (int i = 0; i < numLen; i++)
    {
        reverse[i] = input[numLen - 1 - i];

        if (i == numLen - 1)
        {
            reverse[i + 1] = '\0';
        }
    }

    printf("The reverse number is: %s\n", reverse);
    printf("The original number is: %s\n", input);

    int result = strcmp(input, reverse);
    printf("Result of strcmp gives us: %d\n", result);

    if (strcmp(input, reverse) == 0)
    {
        printf("These numbers are palindromes\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("These numbers are not palindromes\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not handling the strings properly. You should overwrite the `'\n'` with `\0`.

```
    ...
    char input[100];
    char reverse[100];

    int numLen = 0;

    printf("Enter a number\n");
    fgets(input, 100, stdin);
    printf("The number is: %s\n", input);
    input[strcspn(input,"\n")]='\0'; // getting the length of the 
                                     // string without `\n` 
                                     // and overwriting with `\0`
    numLen = strlen(input) ;  // now you don't need to put the -1
    printf("Length of string is: %d\n", numLen);

    for (int i = 0; i < numLen; i++)
    {
        ....
```

Apart from these two changes everything else remains the same. You were reversing it all right. And then you used `strcmp` right way. But the extra `\n` is removed in the code I have shown.

#### (still) Why it works?

Now to give you a better idea. You formed the reversed string alright. But the original string has `\n` within itself.

```
printf("The reverse number is: (%s)\n", reverse);
printf("The original number is: (%s)\n", input);
```

In the previous program you just do write these two lines. You will understand where you went wrong.

On giving input `1001`<kbd>Enter</kbd> it gives this output.

```
The reverse number is: (1001)
The original number is: (1001
)
```

---

#### What is `strcspn` doing?

I have using `strcspn` function got the length without `\n` and overwriting it with `\0`.

```
0 1 2 3  4  5   --> indices
1 0 0 1 \n \0   --> strcspn(input,"\n") returns 4.
1 0 0 1 \0 \0   --> input[strcspn(input,"\n")]='\0'
```

---

You can do simply like this without the copying and everything.

#### Without extra memory - in place palindrome checking

```
bool checkPal(const char *s){
    for(int i = 0, j= strlen(s)-1; i< strlen(s) && j>=0 ; i++)
        if(s[i] != s[j])
            return false;
    return true;
}
int main(void)
{
    char input[100];
    char reverse[100];

    
    printf("Enter a number\n");
    if( fgets(input, 100, stdin) )
    printf("The number is: %s\n", input);
    
    input[strcspn(input,"\n")]='\0';
    int numLen = strlen(input) ;
    printf("Length of string is: %d \n", numLen);
  
    printf("These numbers are %spalindromes\n", checkPal(input)?"not ":"");
    return 0;
}
```

A more succinct way to write the `checkPal()` would be,

```
bool checkPal(const char *first){
    const char *last = first + strlen(first);
    while (first < last) {
       if (*first++ != *--last) {
           return false;
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

`last` points to the `\0` character. Subtraction is necessary before we start doing comparison. To get a clear idea of what happens you have to know the precedence and few rules.

The `first<last` part is obvious. We are comparing till we reach a point where we `first > last` (For even length strings) or `first = last` (for odd length strings).

The `if` is a bit tricky. `*first++` there are two operators involved. `*` (indirection) and `++`(post increment).

And precedence of `++` is higher than de-reference `*`.

So `*first++` will be - first is incremented. Then you might think that we are missing one character very first time but that's not the case. Value of a postfix expression is the value before we do `first++`. So now you have the first character.

Same way `*--last` will have the same effect except the value of the prefix expression is the value after the operation. So you are considering the last character.

If they matches we continue. `first` and `last` already contain the modified value. We repeat the same logic for rest of the characters in the smaller sub-string.

If a mismatch occurs then we return immediately. (Because it's not a palindrome).

Comment: Can you explain why the original one has a \n inside of it? How do I work around that?

Comment: @rsorki.: Wait modifying

Comment: @rsorki.: Check the answer..I have modified it. First one is your code with minimal changes. There is just 2 lines of changes. Check it.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense, thanks so much!

Comment: For a tight `checkPal()`, see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/180994/29485

Comment: @chux.: Only the 3rd point applies to me I guess... `const char *p = s+ strlen(s)` to get the second pointer?

Comment: @coderredoc Yes, for C, `s+ strlen(s)`.

Comment: @chux.: I have tried to add it and explain things. Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my bad. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// A function to check if a string str is palindrome
void isPalindrome(char str[])
{
    // Start from leftmost and rightmost corners of str
    int l = 0;
    int h = strlen(str) - 1;

    // Keep comparing characters while they are same
    while (h > l)
    {
        if (str[l++] != str[h--])
        {
            printf("%s is Not Palindromen", str);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("%s is palindromen", str);
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    isPalindrome("abba");
    isPalindrome("abbccbba");
    isPalindrome("geeks");
    return 0;
}
```

Does this one work?

Comment: Yep this one works! I'm just confused about my method as there has to be an issue with reversing the string. Even if I output both strings and they look the same when compared they are not. I also tried doing comparing them with == like you said but that didn't work either.

Comment: I do not think you need the if statement in the for loop.

Comment: I took out the if statement but I'm still getting the same issue

Comment: This will produce the *exact same problem* for strings read with `fgets`. After `int h = strlen(str) - 1;` you need `if (str[h] == '\n') h--;` (you can add a check of `'\r'` in the conditional if there is a chance you are reading from a file with DOS linebreaks on systems that use `'\n'` for end of line).

Answer (score 0):

A variant, recursive version that has no more that the string as argument (or a copy of the original string)

```
int pal(char *s) {
    int n = strlen(s);
    if (n <= 1) return 1;
    if (s[0] != s[n-1]) return 0;
    s[n-1] = '\0';
    return pal(++s);
}
```

return 0: not a palindrome, 1: is a palindrome

Note the string is altered, so you can call it this way if it's a problem (or if the string is created in a static area)

```
char *copy = malloc(strlen(string)+1); // string is original string
strcpy(copy, string);
int ispal = pal( copy );

printf("Is %s a palindrome\n", ispal ? "":"not");
```